Hyper-V Guest Performance issue
I have issue with my hyper-V guests related to performance, can you please see below my config and i am little bit confuse related to assigning vCPU, I am not sure is that the reason that some VMs performance is very slow over RDP or in Host Server if you connect Hyper v guest, network speed is fine.
Hyper-V Host:
Dell PowerEdge R540, Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4210R CPU @ 2.40GHz, 128GB Ram, Storage Total 8TB RAID-5, Storage Type SAS HDD, Logical Processors 20, Windows Server 2019.
Hyper-V Guests:
Server 1= Gen 2,Config Version 9.0, OS Server 2019, Fixed 8192GB Ram, 2 vCPU assigned - very slow
Applications= Normal softwares accounts related
Server 2= Gen 1, 5.0, Server 2012 R2, Fixed 12288, 2vCPU assigned = working OK
Applications= IIS,SQL Express
Server 3= Gen 2, 9.0, Server 2016, Fixed 16384GB, 2vCPU = working OK
Applications= IIS, MySQL Server
Server 4= Gen 2, 9.0, Server 2019, Fixed 8192GB, 2vCPU = working OK
Applications= AD Server
Server 5= Gen 2, 9.0, Server 2019, Fixed 8192GB, 2vCPU = working OK
Applications= IIS
Server 6= Gen 1, 5.0, Server 2008 R2, Fixed 8192GB, 4vCPU = working OK
Applications= Sharepoint
Server 7= Gen 1, 5.0, Server 2008 R2, Fixed 8192GB, 1vCPU = working OK
Applications= AD Server
Server 8=Gen 2, 9.0, Server 2016, Fixed 16384GB, 4vCPU = very slow
Applications= Trellix ePO and SQL Server 2014 Standard
I have a big performance issue with Server 8, I need to restart every 3-4 days because its just stop responding over RDP, and ePO application work slow after 2 days even automated tasks in epo stopped working.
Thanks in advance.

Additional DB information request from Server 8, please.
OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Post TEXT data FROM Server 8 on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

If you're using SSDs, why are you using RAID?

This question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.
